# Generic transpose (or anything else really!) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, polymorphism

Working on an [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) puzzle I had found myself defining a function to transpose matrices of integers:

```kotlin
fun transpose(xs: Array<Array<Int>>): Array<Array<Int>> {
    val cols = xs[0].size // 3
    val rows = xs.size // 2
    var ys = Array(cols) { Array(rows) { 0 } }
    for (i in 0..rows - 1) {
        for (j in 0..cols - 1)
            ys[j][i] = xs[i][j]
    }
    return ys
}
```

Turns out that in the following puzzle I also needed to transpose a matrix, but it wasn't a matrix of `Int`s, so i tried to generalize. In Haskell I would have had something of type

```hs
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

and to replicate that in Kotlin I tried the following:

```kotlin
fun transpose(xs: Array<Array<Any>>): Array<Array<Any>> {
    val cols = xs[0].size
    val rows = xs.size
    var ys = Array(cols) { Array(rows) { Any() } } // maybe this is the problem?
    for (i in 0..rows - 1) {
        for (j in 0..cols - 1)
            ys[j][i] = xs[i][j]
    }
    return ys
}
```

This seems ok but it isn't. In fact, when I try calling it on the original matrix of integers I get `Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Array<Int>> but Array<Array<Any>> was expected`.
The thing is, I don't really understand this error message: I thought `Any` was a supertype of anything else?

Googling around I thought I understood that I should use some sort of type constraint syntax (sorry, not sure it's called like that in Kotlin), thus changing the type to `fun <T: Any> transpose(xs: Array<Array<T>>): Array<Array<T>>`, but then at the return line I get `Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Array<Any>> but Array<Array<T>> was expected`

So my question is, how do I write a `transpose` matrix that works on any 2-dimensional array?

Comment: If interested, you can see [my solution](https://github.com/ArpitShukIa/AdventOfCode2021/blob/main/src/Day04.kt#L18) for that AdventOfCode puzzle. There I have created a list of columns from list of rows.

Comment: Cool to see another AoC repo in Kotlin! :) Mine is [here](https://github.com/harisont/aoc21). I don't have a lot of time these days so I guess I'll go back to part 2s in the future, so I won't look at your solution not to have any spoilers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, the line `Array(cols) { Array(rows) { Any() } }` creates an `Array<Array<Any>>`, so if you use it in your generic function, you won't be able to return it when `Array<Array<T>>` is expected.

Instead, you should make use of this lambda to directly provide the correct value for the correct index (instead of initializing to arbitrary values and replacing all of them):

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> transpose(xs: Array<Array<T>>): Array<Array<T>> {
    val cols = xs[0].size
    val rows = xs.size
    return Array(cols) { j ->
        Array(rows) { i -> 
            xs[i][j]
        }
    }
}
```

> I don't really understand this error message: I thought Any was a supertype of anything else?

This is because [arrays in Kotlin are invariant in their element type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance). If you don't know about generic variance, it's about describing how the hierarchy of a generic type compares to the hierarchy of their type arguments.

For example, assume you have a type `Foo<T>`. Now, the fact that `Int` is a subtype of `Any` doesn't necessarily imply that `Foo<Int>` is a subtype of `Foo<Any>`. You can look up the jargon, but essentially you have 3 possibilities here:

- We say that `Foo` is *covariant* in its type argument `T` if `Foo<Int>` is a *subtype* of `Foo<Any>` (`Foo` types "vary the same way" as `T`)
- We say that `Foo` is *contravariant* in its type argument `T` if `Foo<Int>` is a *supertype* of `Foo<Any>` (`Foo` types "vary the opposite way" compared to `T`)
- We say that `Foo` is *invariant* in its type argument `T` if none of the above can be said

Arrays in Kotlin are invariant. Kotlin's read-only `List`, however, is *covariant* in the type of its elements. This is why it's ok to assign a `List<Int>` to a variable of type `List<Any>` in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you, this really was a clear and comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Another take on this would be to add a generic extension method to List or Array so you can call `.transpose()` direction on the instance.

```
/**
 * Given a list of lists (ie a matrix), transpose it
 */
fun <T>List<List<T>>.transpose(): List<List<T>> {
    return (this[0].indices).map { i -> (this.indices).map { j -> this[j][i] } }
}

/**
 * Given an array of arrays (ie a matrix), transpose it
 */
inline fun <reified T>Array<Array<T>>.transpose(): Array<Array<T>> {
    return Array(this[0].size) { i -> Array(this.size) { j -> this[j][i] } }
}
```

You can then call this like

```
val rows = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(4, 5, 6), listOf(7, 8, 9))
val columns = rows.transpose()
```

Hope this helps!